# woocommerce : Product price 0 when apply coupon discount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I apply a fixed amount discount coupon on an order, some products price become 0,

can I prevent this by fixing minimum product price (maybe 0,5)

The cart minimum is 300 and coupon can never be more then 50% of the cart total

[image: order details]

Answer (score 0):

After handred of tests and research i found a solution

```
        function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discounting_amount, $price_to_discount , $cart_item, $single, $coupon ) {    
    // On backorder
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_price() - $discounting_amount <= 0 ) {
        $discounting_amount = 0;
    }
    return $discounting_amount;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
```